# Separating out variables from a complex string using Perl

Tags: string, facebook, perl

I have a string like this, returned from a Facebook API call.

```
"'link' => 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/123456789/',
'timezone' => '5.5', 'name' => 'John Smith', 'locale' => 'en_GB',
'last_name' => 'Smith', 'email' => 'myemail@hotmail.com',
'updated_time' => '2015-05-05T15:35:31+0000', 'verified' => bless(
do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ), 'id' => '123456789',
'birthday' => '05/01/1956', 'first_name' => 'John', 'gender' =>
'male'"
```

I want to separate the variables out using Perl, eg. create variables that will contain the value, as follows:

```
$link = 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/123456789/'

$name = 'John Smith'
```

etc.

Having spent hours getting the string finally out of Facebook, now I'm struggling to separate out the variables using substring or hash.

Comment: That return format is simply JSON – and you should not try and go to work on it with string functions, but use whatever JSON parsing functionality Perl provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `... bless( do{(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::PP::Boolean' ), ...` is a giveaway that this is `Data::Dumper` output, which is already a Perl readable expression. Wrap it in braces, `eval` it, and you've got yourself a hash reference.

```
my $fb_output = "'link' => ...  'gender' => 'male'";
my $hashref = eval "{$fb_output}";
print "The last name is ", $hashref->{last_name}, "\n";
...
```

One or two levels up in your code, you are probably receiving a JSON string from Facebook, decoding it into a hash reference, and then converting the hash reference as the above string with `Data::Dumper`. That would be a more appropriate place to work with the data.

Comment: Hi. Yes, very insightful! That is exactly the case. However, I've found that Facebook doesn't seem to return a proper JSON string - I got an error while trying to parse it using JSON and found other people had a similar issue. Hence my fiddling around with Dumper and now trying to parse the string manually. Not pretty, I admit. Thanks for the input and guidance. I will continue trying to work this out!

Comment: Got it working, with your kind help:
...
$user = $fb->fetch('me');
$string = Dumper $user;
$length = length($string);
$string = substr $string, 7, $length-7-2; # this chops off the unnecessary stuff

$hashref = eval "{$string}";
print "The last name is ", $hashref->{last_name}, "\n";

Comment: @Scotsman: from that, it sure looks like `$user` is *not* a string, but the exact same data structure you end up with (so fetch is already doing the json decoding); just do `$user->{last_name}`!

Comment: also, substr can take an offset from the end, so `substr $string, 7, -2`

Comment: What @ysth said. That `fetch` method [returns a hash reference of an object from facebook](https://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook::Graph#fetch-id)